# jQuery: get the sibling of a special parent using closest(), find() and children()

Tags: jquery, html, css, find, parent-child

I faced an issue how to find the URL of a using .closest, .find and probably other methods of jQuery. The structure of the page is:

```
ul
 ul
  ul.good
    li
    ...
    li
    li
      <a href="/findme">findme</a>
      ul
        .
         .
          .
          ul
           li
             a <-this
```

there are many inner lists as you see. 
I need to find the href value of a of li of ul.good. The problem is if I find ul.good using closest(), I'm unable to find the exact li which is parent of **this** where I "came" from moving up to the ul.good.

So, the question is how to get the /findme value from a<-this. Is it possible?

To clarify, the a href /findme is level one within ul.good.

a<-this is much deeper (the level is not known).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a class or some sort of identifier to the `a` with the href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to collect all the `li`-children of `ul.good` first:

```
$goodUl = $this.closest('ul.good');
$lis = $goodUl.children();
```

... then use those as `closest` param:

```
$liParentOfThis = $this.closest($lis);
```

This'll give you the parenting `$li`, then finding `a` should be trivial:

```
$a = $liParentOfThis.children('a');
```

---

That's kind of concise, but not efficient, as you go up the chain twice. You can make it faster with a loop:

```
$check = $this; 
while (($check = $check.parent().closest('ul')).length) {
  if ($check.is('.good')) break; // already went up too far
  $a = $check.prev('a');
  if ($a.length) break; // found it 
}
```

Here at each step you go for the next closest ul (parent is necessary, as `.closest` look up starts from the element itself) and check whether or not it has a previous sibling of `a` you need. If it does, the search is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. Hope this works for you :)

```js
$("#here").on("click",function(){
   alert($(this).parents("ul.good").find("> li > a").attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <ul>
    <ul class="good">
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>
        <a href="/findme">findme</a>
      </li>
    <ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="here">I am here</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```